# How cache and execute in nodejs a call

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application that it's gathering data from another application, both in NodeJS.

I was wondering, how can I trigger sending the data to a third application on certain conditions? For example, every 10 mins if there's data in a bucket or when I have 20 elements to send?
And if the call on the third parties fails, how can I repeat it after 10-15 mins?

EDIT:
The behaviour should be something like:

if you have 1 data posted (axios.post) AND [10 mins passed OR other 10 data posted] SUBMIT to App n.3
What can help me doing so? Can I keep the value saved until those requirements are satisfied?
Thank you <3

Comment: It sounds like you would just use `setTimeout()` to schedule an activity for a specific amount of time in the future.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. This is just part of what I want to achieve, and I think setTimeout is not a good practice on nodejs.

Comment: What do you mean `setTimeout()` is not a good practice?  That's just wrong.  Timers in nodejs are extremely efficient and they are the preferred mechanism for scheduling something to repeat in 15 minutes.

Comment: You are completely mistaken here.  `setTimeout()` is EXACTLY how you schedule something to run at some time in the future in nodejs.  I will be happy to leave this question alone since you refuse to accept advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use packages like `node-schedule` which is popular to schedule tasks. When callback runs check if there is enough data(posts) to send.